# Software to auto update Windows 7 time/date from a master computer

Tags: windows-7, network-administration

I manage a very small internal network in my classroom. None of the computers, not even mine, have access to the internet. I'd like to be able to install one small piece of software on each of the student's computers that looks at my computer and updates it's time/date to be synchronized with mine.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

There is not domain controller in the classroom, only 20 student computers and my teacher computer. They are all running Windows 7 Pro x64.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the responsibility of a **ntp server** software to do this.  [image]  After setting up the ntp server on your PC enter the IP address of your PC onto each classroom PC and your done.

I found a link with some detailed instructions.
http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/setup.html
Other **ntp server** products exist if you don't like that one.

Comment: Sweet! I honestly didn't even know what to Google to at least look for something like this myself. I appreciate you very much! I'll give this a shot Tuesday when I'm back in the classroom.